# How to avoid to broadcast a large lookup table in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Can you help me to avoid broadcasting of a large lookup table? I have a table with measurements:

```
Measurement     Value
x1              5.1
x2              8.9
x1              9.1
x3              4.4
x2              2.1
...
```

And a list of pairs:

```
P1              P2
x1              x2
x2              x3
...
```

The task is to get all values for both elements of every pair and put them into a magic function. That's how I solved it by broadcasting the large table with the measurements.

```scala
case class Measurement(measurement: String, value: Double)
case class Candidate(c1: String, c2: String)

val measurements = Seq(Measurement("x1", 5.1), Measurement("x2", 8.9), 
  Measurement("x1", 9.1), Measurement("x3", 4.4))
val candidates = Seq(Candidate("x1", "x2"), Candidate("x2", "x3"))

// create data frames
val dfm = sqc.createDataFrame(measurements)
val dfc = sqc.createDataFrame(candidates)

// broadcast lookup table
val lookup = sc.broadcast(dfm.rdd.map(r => (r(0), r(1))).collect())

// udf: run magic test with every candidate
val magic: ((String, String) => Double) = (c1: String, c2: String) => {
  val lt = lookup.value

  val c1v = lt.filter(_._1 == c1).map(_._2).map(_.asInstanceOf[Double])
  val c2v = lt.filter(_._1 == c2).map(_._2).map(_.asInstanceOf[Double])

  new Foo().magic(c1v, c2v)
}

val sq1 = udf(magic)
val dfks = dfc.withColumn("magic", sq1(col("c1"), col("c2")))
```

As you can guess I'm not pretty happy with the solution. For every pair I filter the lookup table twice, this isn't fast nor elegant. I'm using Spark 1.6.1.

Comment: This full scans leading to Cartesian product look much worse than broadcast. Also if you really want to avoid broadcast why not use `join`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative would be to use RDD and join. Not sure what's better in term of performance though.

```
case class Measurement(measurement: String, value: Double)
case class Candidate(c1: String, c2: String)

val measurements = Seq(Measurement("x1", 5.1), Measurement("x2", 8.9), 
Measurement("x1", 9.1), Measurement("x3", 4.4))
val candidates = Seq(Candidate("x1", "x2"), Candidate("x2", "x3"))

val rdm = sc.parallelize(measurements).map(r => (r.measurement, r.value)).groupByKey().cache()
val rdc = sc.parallelize(candidates).map(r => (r.c1, r.c2)).cache()

val firstColJoin = rdc.join(rdm).values
val secondColJoin = firstColJoin.join(rdm).values

secondColJoin.map { case (c1v, c2v) => new Foo().magic(c1v, c2v) }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all comments. I read the comments, did some research and studied [zero323](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1560062/zero323) posts.

My current solution is using two `joins` and an `UserDefinedAggregateFunction`:

```scala
object GroupValues extends UserDefinedAggregateFunction {
  def inputSchema = new StructType().add("x", DoubleType)
  def bufferSchema = new StructType().add("buff", ArrayType(DoubleType))
  def dataType = ArrayType(DoubleType)
  def deterministic = true

  def initialize(buffer: MutableAggregationBuffer) = {
    buffer.update(0, ArrayBuffer.empty[Double])
  }

  def update(buffer: MutableAggregationBuffer, input: Row) = {
    if (!input.isNullAt(0))
      buffer.update(0, buffer.getSeq[Double](0) :+ input.getDouble(0))
  }

  def merge(buffer1: MutableAggregationBuffer, buffer2: Row) = {
    buffer1.update(0, buffer1.getSeq[Double](0) ++ buffer2.getSeq[Double](0))
  }

  def evaluate(buffer: Row) = buffer.getSeq[Double](0)
}

// join data for candidate one
val j1 = dfc.join(dfm, dfc("c1") === dfm("measurement"))

// aggregate all c1 values to an array
val j1v = j1.groupBy(col("c1"), col("c2")).agg(GroupValues(col("value"))
  .alias("c1-values"))

// join data for candidate two
val j2 = j1v.join(dfm, j1v("c2") === dfm("measurement"))

// aggregate all c2 values to an array
val j2v = j2.groupBy(col("c1"), col("c2"), col("c1-values"))
  .agg(GroupValues(col("value")).alias("c2-values"))
```

Next step would be to use `collect_list` instead of `UserDefinedAggregateFunction`.